# Kind of logical subtraction

Tags: binary, boolean-logic

Having these two bitsets as an example:

```
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```

How can I get this following result:

```
0 1 0 0
```

From my point of view this kind of logic operation must be a subtraction but omitting the borrow bit.

Is it possible to have a simple logical operation to get that result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there's an infinite number of solutions... Can you please detail a bit more?

Comment: This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is only true, if `A` is true and `B` is false.
 So it can be solved as  `A & ~B`

Comment: Using typical bitwise operators of programming languages, it's ~B, not !B.

Comment: Thanks gkovacs90. That's exactly what I was looking for.